# Typescript, @ngrx and default store values

Tags: typescript, angular, ngrx

I think I am missing something obvious trying to work with [@ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store). I am trying to use nested reducers, and want to be able to return default starting child values. This is my child

```
export const counter:Reducer<number> = 
    (state:number = 0, action:Action = {type:null}) => {

    switch (action.type) {
```

My question is how to use this to initialise an extra counter. My counters.ts looks like

```
export const counters:Reducer<number[]> = (state:number[] = [], action:Action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_COUNTER:
            return [counter(), ...state];
```

This works but I have a typescript error on counter: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target` and I'm wondering how to get around this.

I'm using @ngrx, which provides this:

```
export interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
}

export interface Reducer<T> {
  (state: T, action: Action): T;
}

export class Store<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
    private _storeSubscription: Subscription<T>
    constructor(private _dispatcher:Dispatcher<Action>, private _reducers:{[key:string]:Reducer<any>}, initialState: T) {
    super(initialState);
    let rootReducer = this._mergeReducers(_reducers, initialState);
    this._storeSubscription = rootReducer.subscribe(this);
    }
```

Comment: What's the definition of `Reducer`? Ok, I guess it's this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/redux-actions/redux-actions.d.ts

Comment: I've added it as it is coming from a new Angular2 library

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `Reducer` should be

```
export interface Reducer<T> {
    (state?: T, action?: Action): T;
}
```

to actually allow calling it without parameters.

Default parameter values are only allowed in constructor and function implementations (like you do in the lambda), so you can't specify default values in the interface definition.

When you call `counter()` the TypeScript compiler will actually check its type (`Reducer<number>`) and will see that two parameters are required.

So you either do what I suggested above or actually call it with the default parameters:

```
counter(0, {type: null})
```

Comment: I've moved this to https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/32. To my mind it makes better design sense if the parent does not need to know the definition of the child to be able to add a new child to the global model - at least that it was what I am used to in Elm

Answer (score 0):

The [suggestion}(https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/32) I ended up using was to drop the Reducer part of the type signature for child reducers. Not very elegant though I fear.